# MS Terminal Server - How to set IE 8 default settings for everyone?

Tags: terminal-server, internet-explorer

I just upgraded to IE 8 on our Terminal Server, but it asks everyone for 
search engine, turn on/off suggestions, etc.

Is there a way I can force one default setting for everyone through Group Policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure can. In your Group Policy Editor

Go to

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer
```

and set

```
Prevent performance of First Run Customize Settings
```

to

```
Enabled
```

You can aso then set whether the browser will display the your default home page, or the 'Welcome to IE' page.

Comment: That setting is actually under User Configuration.

Comment: Also: Duh! I don't know why I didn't think of using the GPO setting instead of a reg hack.

Comment: Have another look. It's under both.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know about setting any particular default settings but you can disable the first run wizard by putting the following into a reg file and importing it to the terminal server:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"DisableFirstRunCustomize"=dword:00000001